# Java Multithreading example

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm a Java student and this is my attempt of implementing a StackExchange (there's a pusher thread and a popper thread, a single stack resource and two controlling Threads for the stack content and time passing).

I was hoping if someone could comment my code for improvements or errors\bad practices, even if the code seems to work.

The main reason of this program was to figure out how to control resource access in a multithreading environment.

I have concerns about the use of the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor rather than locking(the stack), and my usage of synchronized in the StackExchange class methods(for accessing the stack), I would like to spawn free threads working on a dynamically locked resource. Any advice?

NB:"Format of magic numbers and syso's may be awful for testing porpuses

code here:

```
package examples;

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Stack;

import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class StackExchange {

    /*
     * Two Threads playing with a stack, a timer and a controller for the stack that permits to exit
     * */
    public class Popper implements Runnable
    {
        StackExchange sEx;
        public Popper(StackExchange sex)
        {
            this.sEx=sex;

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Popper: popping!\t"+sEx.getPeek());
            sEx.callTheStack(this, null);
        }
    }
    public class Pusher implements Runnable
    {
        StackExchange sEx;
        public Pusher(StackExchange sex)
        {
            sEx=sex;        
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Pusher: pushing!\t");
            sEx.callTheStack(this, "Hi!");
        }
    }
    public class StackController implements Runnable
    {
        private Stack<String> theStack;
        public int waiting=5;
        public StackController(Stack<String> theStack, String name) {
            this.theStack =  theStack;
            Thread.currentThread().setName(name);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            waiting = rand.nextInt(10);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            int i=0;
            for(String string: theStack)
            {
                buffer.append(string+"\n");
                i++;
            }
            buffer.append("\nFound "+i+" elements\nIWillWait4:\t"+waiting);

            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"+Thread.currentThread().getName().toString()+" Says:" + buffer.toString());
            if(i>1)
            {
                System.out.println("ERRER");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(i==1 && JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,  "found 1 element\nWannaStop?")==0)
                System.exit(0);


        }
    }
    public class Timer implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            StackExchange.time++;
            System.out.println("Time Passed:\t"+StackExchange.time+" seconds");
        }

    }
    /*
     * implementation of the StackExchange class
     * */
    private Popper popper;
    private Pusher pusher;  
    private StackController stackController;
    private StackController secondSC;
    private Timer timer;

    static int time=0;

    private Stack<String> stack;

    public StackExchange()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        stack = new Stack<String>();
        pusher = new Pusher(this);
        popper = new Popper(this);
        stackController = new StackController(this.getStack(), "FirstStackController");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackExchange sex = new StackExchange();
        sex.start();
        System.out.println("Num of Threads:"+Thread.activeCount());
    }
    public void start()
    {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(pusher, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(popper, 1, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(stackController, 0, stackController.waiting, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
    }
    public Stack<String >getStack()
    {
        return this.stack;
    }
    public void callTheStack(Object caller, String pushedString)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            if(caller instanceof Popper)
                stack.pop();

            else if(caller instanceof Pusher)
                stack.push(pushedString);
        }
    }
    public String getPeek()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            return stack.peek();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should place your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it I'd a request for a code review.

Answer (score 0):

Things that might help:

- Don't use `java.util.Stack`.

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
>   provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
>   be used in preference to this class.
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

- Your nested subclasses of `StackExchange` are all inner classes so
  that means they already have a reference to the containing
  `StackExchange` instance
- and its member `stack` instance, which should be `final`.
- So don't pass them as parameters. This simplifies logic, maintenance,
  and GC.
- `caller instanceof Popper` this type of reflection is utterly
  unnecessary and breaks object orientation.
- You know that `Object` is too broad a type for `callTheStack` (weak
  name). In fact, you know that the object will be a `Runnable`, but
  more importantly, the `Runnable` should know what to do already.
- Synchronization should be kept minimal to just the *critical section* that shares data and no more, shown below using the `synchronized` keyword
- or to just the *memory boundary*, shown below using the `volatile` keyword
- and member variables of a containing class are a great way to share data between threads within the class.

Example

```
public class StackExchange {

private final Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
private volatile boolean running;

private void consume(String item) {
  // ...
}

private String obtain() {
  // ...
}

private boolean getPermission() {
  // ...
}

// getters, setters, ... 

private final Runnable consumer = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (running) {
      final String popped;
      synchronized(stack) {
        popped = stack.pollFirst();
      }
      consume(popped);
    }
  }
};

private final Runnable producer = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   while (running) {
     final String pushing = obtain();
      synchronized(stack) {
        stack.offerFirst(pushing);
      }
    }
  }
};

public static void main(String ... args) {
  StackExchange exchange = new StackExchange();

  exchange.setRunning(true);
  new Thread(exchange.getConsumer()).start();
  new Thread(exchange.getProducer()).start();

  do  {
  } while (exchange.getPermission());

  exchange.setRunning(false);
}
}
```

It's a good idea to declare member variables prior to member methods.

I put the `Runnable` code in anonymous classes to leave the code at the very edge of using lambdas.

The idea behind `consume`, `obtain`, and `getPermission` is to hint at how the code would interact with the business logic that doesn't know about threading. These could be implemented as callbacks or abstract methods.

One good thing about `Deque` is that it can easily be set up for a FIFO queue.

Just for fun, convert those `Runnable` instances into lambdas, and make the `StackExchange` class generic.

Hot question: what other subtypes of `Deque<E>` might suit, and what advantages or disadvantages would they have? What code changes might need to happen to accommodate them?